# Inline advertising inside of a view

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I want to have my advertising a little more subtly included into my page, kind of like how Instagram has been doing it.

Instead of having it awkwardly on the side, or at the top, I want ads to appear on my pages as part of my view. Right now my view is displaying content type article, but I would like 1 for every 20 or so articles to instead display a advertisement.

Is it possible to have views render inline advertisements in this manner?

like this mockup.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.cmsquickstart.com/blog/tutorial-better-advertisement-integration-drupal-7-views) explains exactly what you are looking for.

You can also try [SimpleAds](https://www.drupal.org/project/simpleads) module and [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52924/insert-whatever-every-nth-row-in-views) on stack.